# How can I fix the following error: ""Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController' to type 'UITextFieldDelegate?'"?

Tags: xcode

I'm new to all this so please keep that in mind while reading.

This is the code I am using; the file refuses to build because of line 16. The error says "Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController' to type 'UITextFieldDelegate?'".

```
//  
//  ViewController.swift  
//  FoodTracker  
//  
//  

import UIKit  

class ViewController: UIViewController {  
    //MARK: Properties  
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!  
    @IBOutlet weak var mealNameLabel: UILabel!  

    override func viewDidLoad() {  
        super.viewDidLoad()  
        nameTextField.delegate = self  
        // Handle the text field’s user input through delegate callbacks.  
    }  
    //MARK: UITextFieldDelegate  
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {  
        //Hide the keyboard  
        textField.resignFirstResponder()  

        return true  
    }  

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {  
        mealNameLabel.text = textField.text  
    }  

    //MARK: Actions  
    @IBAction func setDefaultLabelText(_ sender: UIButton) {  
        mealNameLabel.text = "Default Text"  
    }  

}
```

Here is the full error output message.

```
020-04-09 14:19:12.897243-0400 FoodTracker[29402:868329] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<FoodTracker.ViewController 0x7ffaef406830> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key nameTypeField.'

*** First throw call stack:

(

  0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e3dcce __exceptionPreprocess + 350

  1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff50b3b9b2 objc_exception_throw + 48

  2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e3d899 -[NSException raise] + 9

  3   Foundation                          0x00007fff258d5796 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 325

  4   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff485689b6 -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 87

  5   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48874ad3 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109

  6   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e29fe2 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 242

  7   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48871cbc -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 2192

  8   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4856fdbe -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 379

  9   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff485708f5 -[UIViewController loadView] + 177

  10  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48570bf4 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 172

  11  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff485713a1 -[UIViewController view] + 27

  12  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48c51ae1 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 326

  13  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48c5110a -[UIWindow _updateLayerOrderingAndSetLayerHidden:actionBlock:] + 219

  14  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48c52195 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 362

  15  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48c655bc -[UIWindow _mainQueue_makeKeyAndVisible] + 42

  16  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48e84d2c -[UIWindowScene _makeKeyAndVisibleIfNeeded] + 202

  17  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48177720 +[UIScene _sceneForFBSScene:create:withSession:connectionOptions:] + 1405

  18  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48c15561 -[UIApplication _connectUISceneFromFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 1019

  19  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48c15898 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 291

  20  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4876a160 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 361

  21  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff36c6091e -[FBSSceneImpl _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 419

  22  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff36c869b1 __86-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:createWithParameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.154 + 102

  23  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff36c6b347 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 220

  24  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff36c86642 __86-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:createWithParameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 355

  25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001075eee8e _dispatch_client_callout + 8

  26  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001075f1da2 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 300

  27  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff36cac2d9 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 30

  28  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff36cabfc7 -[FBSSerialQueue _queue_performNextIfPossible] + 441

  29  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff36cac4d6 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 22

  30  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23da1c71 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17

  31  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23da1b9c __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 76

  32  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23da13cc __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 268

  33  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d9bf6e __CFRunLoopRun + 974

  34  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d9b884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 404

  35  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff38b5ac1a GSEventRunModal + 139

  36  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48c19220 UIApplicationMain + 1605

  37  FoodTracker                         0x000000010737880b main + 75

  38  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff519b910d start + 1

  39  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1

)

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: "Refuse to build" and crash on runtime? That's contradictory. For your crash, you had previsouly a var named `nameTypeField`? It's in the Interface, but not in code, look for that error, it's a well known one.

Comment: You didn't say that `ViewController` can be delegate of the textfield. In otherwords, that it's compliant with `UITextFieldDelegate` => `class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate`

Comment: Yeah sorry, I'm not too well-versed with all the lingo. The apple tutorial seems quite outdated actually, do you have any recommended tutorials that I can follow to learn Xcode and are more recent?